# Validation script only firing once & can't select specific radio parent div

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to get a couple of javascripts scripts to work properly.

The first is a simple validation script on the textbox. It works once but if you hit the submit a second time you can proceed without entering anything. How do I make the script to fire (and work) every time the submit button is clicked?

The second thing I'm trying to do is get a div class to change based on a radio click . The problem is that because all the radio buttons share the same id/name it always changes the first radio button background no matter which radio button was clicked. How do I get it to change the class of the div containing it?

HTML looks like (with the javascript in the head tags as shown...

```
<head>
<link href="/css/0051.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
        var x=document.forms["form"]["txtbox_1501"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="" || x=="Please type your answer in this box")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtbox_container").id = "txtbox_err";
        document.getElementById("ques_txt").className = "ques_txt_err";
        document.getElementById("ques_inst").className = "ques_inst_err";
        return false;
    }
}

function radioDiv() {
    document.getElementById("radio_label").className = "radio_input_selected";
}

</script>

</head>

<body>


<form id="form" name ="form" action="/php/process.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()"  method="post">

<div id="txtbox_container">
       <div id="ques_container">
          <a id="ques_txt" class="ques_txt">Please tell us your name:</br></a>
          <a id="ques_inst" class="ques_inst">(How you would like to be referred to in this demo)</br></a>
       </div>
       <div id="txtbox_input">
          <input type="text" name="txtbox_1501" value="Please type your answer in this box" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;" /></br>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div id="radio_container">
       <div id="ques_container">
          <a class="ques_txt">What is your gender?</br></a>
          <a class="ques_inst">(Are you female or male?)</br></a>
       </div>
       <label>
          <div id="radio_label" class="radio_input">
             <input type="radio" name="radio_1503" value="2" onclick="return radioDiv()" />
             <a class="radio_label">Female</a>
          </div>
       </label>
       <label>
          <div id="radio_label" class="radio_input">
             <input type="radio" name="radio_1503" value="1" onclick="return radioDiv()" />
             <a class="radio_label">Male</a>
          </div>
       </label></div> 
</div>      

<div id="button">
   <input type="submit" class="submitbutton" value=""/>

</div>  

    </form>

</body>
```

Any suggestions would be gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: You can't have 2 elements with the same `id`. It's invalid HTML. `ID`s are unique. Let alone `</br>` and some other invalid markups..

Comment: Note that the [Type](http://es5.github.com/#x8) of a [form control value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2) is always [String](http://es5.github.com/#x8.4), therefore `x==null` will always return false (see the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I make the script to fire (and work) every time the submit
>   button is clicked?

The first time you run this line of code:

```
document.getElementById("txtbox_container").id = "txtbox_err";
```

Is properly executed. However, in any following call, you won't be able to `getElementById` passing an `id` which no longer exists! (you just overwrote that element's `id` by another one)

So, `getElementById("txtbox_container")` returns `null` from the 2nd call onwards, and trying to set the `id` property of `null` yields this fatal error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null

Which breaks your function before returning `false` which makes the form submit normally.

You can either just comment that line out, or if you need styling change/add a CSS `class` instead of changing the `id`.

> How do I get it to change the class of the div containing it?

You can't have 2 elements with same `id` as it's invalid markup. Instead, pass the reference to the clicked radio button element (`this`) to your function and get its `parentNode` to change the styling as you want:

```
//HTML
onclick="return radioDiv(this)"
//JS
function radioDiv(el) {
    el.parentNode.className = "radio_input radio_input_selected";
}
```

I'm keeping the original class as well, as you probably want to reset the `radio` elements in case the user selects another `radio`:

```
function radioDiv(el) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByClassName('radio_input');
    //could use a for loop to reset these, but there are only 2 radios...
    radios[0].className = "radio_input"; radios[1].className = "radio_input";
    el.parentNode.className = "radio_input radio_input_selected";
}​
```

Here you go.

***[JSFiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/U86AW/)***

***Tips:***

Always validate your HTML, a sturdy DOM structure is a must for any good JS coding. The W3C validation service may be a little too demanding, but any good markup highlighter program can show you unclosed and invalid syntax tags - even the [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) online editor.

**Always check your JS console for errors:**
Firefox: **Ctrl+Shift+K** (or install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and press F12);
Chrome: Press **F12** and select the **Console** tab.

This will display errors which may break your code like this one, so you may post it in your questions if you can't solve them next time. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the solutions and general pointers they all very very useful.